# Google app engine vs web hosting (unlimited traffic)

Tags: google-app-engine, web-hosting

My current web hosting company offers me unlimited traffic, space etc. 
Why should I want google app engine?

What does it offer me more than traditional web hosting ?

Thank you

Comment: I find that hard to believe.  How much are you paying? What would happen if you suddenly upload 10GB of ISOs?

Comment: Unlimited traffic? Would you mind sharing the name of this hosting company?

Comment: Hosting companies, telcos, ... like to redefine the word "unlimited"

Comment: Right, @Mehrdad. It's really, 'unlimited until we think that you have used too much. You'll know because your application will disappear.'

Comment: There are many companies which have unlimited hosting, from 3$ to ... But good question with the 10g iso

Comment: 1and1.com offers "unlimited" storage and bandwidth, but have a 20MB POST limit.

Comment: -1 .  your web hosting company does not offer you unlimited traffic or space.  if they did, you could start your own business reselling web hosting to facebook, amazon, and youtube, and make a fortune.  There is a limit, you just haven't read the fine print, or else they lied to you.

Comment: @HJ-INCPP They **say** they have unlimited hosting, but plenty of companies say their sugar pills cure cancer. Unlimited is simply **not** possible.  Try it out - write a script that continually creates massive amounts of data, and see how long until they kick you off the service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current web hosting doesn't actually offer you unlimited traffic or space. If you tried to run Facebook on it, your site would either not work or they'd find an excuse to drop you. Bandwidth, servers, and storage are expensive in large quantities.

Google App Engine and systems like it are suitable for massive, scalable sites. If you're fine with your current hosting, there's little reason to switch.

Answer (score 4):

- The reliability of a big name like Google
- Faster hardware and better connections
- <strike>Truly</strike>Almost unlimited scalability

Comment: Well, even Google doesn't have truly unlimited scalability. They are still constrained by finite pipes and data centers. What do offer is extreme scalability without any need to make code or infrastructure changes.

Comment: @Adam: I highly doubt that any site on Google App Engine will consume more bandwidth than Google itself.

Comment: For all reasonable purposes it's safe to say they are infinitely scalable

Comment: I entirely agree with your point, but 'truly unlimited scalability' has as much wrong with it as OP's 'unlimited traffic, badwidth, etc.' There's no need for such hyperbole. AppEngine is an amazing service, but I think that over-selling it does it a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

As with other answers above answers you get the reliability of a big name like Google and truly unlimited scalability but if you like your current webhost you could set up a Google App Engine Account to use as a [bandwidth-limit free Content Delivery Network](http://24ways.org/2008/using-google-app-engine-as-your-own-cdn). If that's what your looking for then 24ways has a great article on how to set it up. I can vouch from personal experience that it is *extremely* reliable and easy to use.

Hope that helps,